# How validate request with custom FormRequest without dependency injection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I validate requests using **FormRequest**. This is a great tool, but I ran into a problem. Making standard identical methods for controllers, I decided to put these methods in a basic abstract class. But in this case, I can't validate requests using FormRequest, since they are transmitted using DI. I found the following solution that partially solved this problem:

```php
/** @var FormRequest $customForRequest */
$customForRequest = $requestModel::createFrom($this->request);
return Validator::make($this->request->all(), $customForRequest->rules())->validate();
```

But the **withValidator** method, which in the standard scenario works as an after hook, is not called in this situating. How can this method be forced to be executed, leaving the validation logic in a separate class?

My FormRequest:

```php
class MassUpdateDocumentAttribute extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'filter' => 'required|array',
            'filter.id.*' => [
                'sometimes',
                'integer',
                Rule::exists(DocumentAttribute::class, 'id')
            ],
            'fields' => 'required|array',
            'fields.document_id' => [
                'sometimes',
                Rule::exists(Document::class, 'id'),
            ],
            'fields.document_attr_type_id' => [
                'required_with:fields.value',
                Rule::exists(DocumentAttrType::class, 'id'),
            ],
            'fields.value' => [
                'sometimes',
                'bail',
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function withValidator(Validator $validator)
    {
        if ($validator->fails()) return;

        $validator->after(function ($validator) use ($documentAttributeRepository, $documentAttrTypeRepository) {
            $data = $validator->getData();

           // some large logic

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `app(YourRequest::class)`, that should automatically validate as well.

Comment: This solution is work! But how i can get only validated data? iI tried it like this:
```app($requestModel);```
```$customForRequest = $requestModel::createFrom($this->request);```
 ```return Validator::make($this->request->all(), $customForRequest->rules())->validate();
```
but i got all request data. Usually i dont get fields if field not exist in rules

Comment: I've added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Answer is working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to instantiate your FormRequest class by simply calling `app(YourRequest::class)` inside the method. It will automatically validate. This way you can simply pass the `YourRequest::class` part as a variable to desired FormRequest and it all should be working.

```php
$request = app(YourRequest::class);

$data = $request->validated();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is works! )
As far as I understand, the array properties remain in the data even if they are not in the rules.